# 3-level ExpandableListView in Android Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I've readymade 2-level working code for ExpandableListView, but when I'm modifying for 3rd one according to that, it's just not happening!

Code:

```
    @Composable
fun CollapsableLazyColumn(
    sections: List<CollapsableSection>,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    val collapsedState = remember(sections) { sections.map { true }.toMutableStateList() }
    LazyColumn(modifier) {
        sections.forEachIndexed { i, dataItem ->
            val collapsed = collapsedState[i]
            item(key = "header_$i") {
                Row(
                    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .clickable {
                            collapsedState[i] = !collapsed
                        }
                ) {
                    Icon(
                        Icons.Default.run {
                            if (collapsed)
                                KeyboardArrowDown
                            else
                                KeyboardArrowUp
                        },
                        contentDescription = "",
                        tint = Color.LightGray,
                    )
                    Text(
                        dataItem.title,
                        fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .padding(vertical = 10.dp)
                            .weight(1f)
                    )
                }
                Divider()
            }
            if (!collapsed) {
                items(dataItem.rows) { row ->
                    Row {
                        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.size(MaterialIconDimension.dp))
                        Text(
                            row,
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .padding(vertical = 10.dp)
                        )
                    }
                    Divider()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

data class CollapsableSection(val title: String, val rows: List<String>)

const val MaterialIconDimension = 24f
```

Usage:

```
CollapsableLazyColumn(
    sections = listOf(
        CollapsableSection(
            title = "Fruits A",
            rows = listOf("Apple", "Apricots", "Avocado")
        ),
        CollapsableSection(
            title = "Fruits B",
            rows = listOf("Banana", "Blackberries", "Blueberries")
        ),
        CollapsableSection(
            title = "Fruits C",
            rows = listOf("Cherimoya", "Cantaloupe", "Cherries", "Clementine")
        ),
    ),
)
```

Result:

[image]

Problem:
For the 3rd level implementation, I'm not able to write this below similar-statement outside of item() because it's not in now inside LazyColumn

```
val subCollapsedState = remember(sections) { sections.map { true }.toMutableStateList() }

enter code here
```

Inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/users/3585796/phil-dukhov

Comment: Could you please answer? https://stackoverflow.com/users/3585796/phil-dukhov